# Uncaught TypeError: setting getter-only property "configureStore"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

Why am I getting the following error while trying to create a store with redux-toolkit?

`Uncaught TypeError: setting getter-only property "configureStore"`

This is my `scr/store/index.js`:

```js
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import uiSlice from "./ui-slice";

const store = configureStore = ({
  reducer: {
    ui: uiSlice.reducer
  }
})

export default store;
```

And this is my `src/index.js`

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { Provider } from 'react';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import store from './store/index';
 
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
);
```

I've followed `redux-toolkit` documentation as I did previously in other projects and I never had this error before. Am I omitting something?

Comment: It's a syntax error, you used double equals:

```
const store = configureStore = ({
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this line:  `const store = configureStore = ({`  
is either some new JS syntax that I don't know or a syntax error.

try this:

```
const store = configureStore({
reducer: {ui: uiSlice.reducer},
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is because of not importing redux?

```js
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
```

Answer (score 0):

`configureStore` is a function you've imported but are trying to overwrite the value. It should be called, e.g. `const store = configureStore({ .... });`.

```js
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import uiSlice from "./ui-slice";

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    ui: uiSlice.reducer
  }
});

export default store;
```

`Provider` is also imported from `react-redux`, not `react`.

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import React, { StrictMode } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import store from './store';
 
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </StrictMode>
);
```